# Azure function poison queue will crash whole job function?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, sendgrid

I think it's a wire question, my situation is someone register an account to azure function, this function will add this account email and some messages to the queue. Queue trigger will trigger SendGrid to send something.

But a few days ago, some of the poison queues occurs, I find someone email format is incorrect. The strange thing is just one job function occurs poison, other job functions will not work, but redeploy will let it work for a while.
According to Microsoft document queue just execute 5 times and move to poison queue when all these fail.

The question is

1. When redeploying Azure job function, this poison queue will be retry?
2. Is it possible for such one job function error to cause the whole job function shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it wont retry poison queue
2. No, if the message errors - it gets put into a poison queue after a certain amount of retries and thats it for that message